# One xml and several xsl (several views)

Tags: xml, xslt

I give you a bit of context to explain my problem:

I have one xml file and one xsl file like this:

data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="overview.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
 </catalog>
```

and overview.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open data.xml in Firefox, everything is fine and works like I want. 
Now, I would like to have 2 views of my CD catalog. One view is an "overview" and one is "extended", it means, I need 2 different xsl.

I tried this:

view1.xml:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="overview.xsl"?>
<xml-file href="data.xml" />
```

view2.xml:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="extended.xsl"?>
<xml-file href="data.xml" />
```

and I removed ths line:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="overview.xsl"?>
```

from data.xml

I was hoping to be able to read my CD catalog with the overview.xsl while reading view1.xml and to read the same CD catalog but with the format from extended.xsl while reading view2.xml.

But it only partially works. Somehow my overview.xsl can not find the nodes anymore. I obtain a webpage with the title, ab html table but no data in it. I think, I need to change the:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
```

to something else. Do you have any idea?

As info, I am trying to do this without using javascript to load another xsl file.

Thanks for your help.
Julie

Comment: Try `select="//cd"` as a test. That should select all `cd` elements regardless of position in the document. If that fails, something else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the same result... Something else should be wrong..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got the idea of `<xml-file>` from: it's a new one for me. But you could make it work by processing it in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="xml-file">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)/catalog"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Just be careful about the match="/" template which now matches the root of either document, which could easily cause infinite recursion.

The alternative, which you'll need to do if things get any more complex, is to write client-side Javascript to invoke the transformation instead of using the xml-stylesheet processing instruction.